# How to achieve rounded corners on new OutlinedButton widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

With Flutter 1.22 we received a new widget `OutlinedButton` which is made to replace `OutlineButton` but how we can actually make its border rounded? `borderSide` and `shape` properties are not available anymore.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can use `OutlinedButton.styleFrom` property:

```
OutlinedButton(
   style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
      ),
      side: BorderSide(width: 2, color: Colors.green),
   ),
   onPressed: () {},
   child: Text('Button'),
)
```

From the source code

````
 /// All parameters default to null, by default this method returns
 /// a [ButtonStyle] that doesn't override anything.
 ///
 /// For example, to override the default shape and outline for an
 /// [OutlinedButton], one could write:
 ///
 /// ```dart
 /// OutlinedButton(
 ///   style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
 ///      shape: StadiumBorder(),
 ///      side: BorderSide(width: 2, color: Colors.green),
 ///   ),
 /// )
 /// ```
````

Answer (score 6):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

If you need some extra control over the style like border should be ABC when the button is pressed, DEF when its hovered... XYZ when not interacted, you can use `ButtonStyle`.

```dart
OutlinedButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  style: ButtonStyle(
    shape: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<OutlinedBorder?>((states) {
      // Rounded button (when the button is pressed)
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
        return RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20));
      }
    }),
  ),
  child: Text('OutlinedButton'),
)
```